# SD card not formatted when using a Windows PC

Tags: debian, storage, sd-card

I have installed Cubian on an SD card and use it to run a Cubieboard which works absolutely fine, but now when I plug the SD card into a window system to make copies, Windows says the card isn't formatted and needs formatting. Is there a reason Windows is saying it isn't formatted but it can boot an OS perfectly fine on the Cuebieboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because Windows isn't able to read the filesystem on the card.
Windows can only read FAT, NTFS, exFAT, Live File System filesystems. Linux, on the other hand, is able to read your card's filesystem, Windows filesystems and other just fine (Linux ftw).

I assume that the filesystem on your card is ext*, so you can use [this](http://www.ext2fsd.com) to install a driver for ext2,3,4 filesystems so you can read and write to them (at your own risk).

Comment: yeah I fired it up in my Linux machine (my main system) and it read it straight away and then I just did a simple DD to create an image and then write it to another card. Silly me thinking Windows would be able to just read the SD card like Linux does, but I suppose that's why I don't use Windows often.